# Pasar un StringJson a jsonObject y editar lo en Java

Tags: java

Buenas tardes Compañeros, tengo un StringJson y me gustaría pasar lo a un JsonObject, editar el campo que necesito y volver a pasar lo ya editado a un String. pero realmente no se como hacer lo alguien me podría ayudar con eso he intentado utilizar la libreria de Gson pero no funciona o no se exactamente como formular la sentencia.
Muchísimas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

Primero convierte tu JsonString a JsonObject:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonElement element = gson.fromJson (jsonStr, JsonElement.class);
JsonObject jsonObj = element.getAsJsonObject();
```

Recuerda que JsonElement es una clase representa cualquier elemento del Json que puede ser de alguno de los siguientes 4 tipos:

JsonObject: Esta clase representa un objeto en el Json; es decir, un conjunto de pares clave-valor donde las claves son strings y los valores son cualquier otro tipo de JsonElement.

JsonArray: Esta clase representa un array en el Json. Un array es una lista de JsonElements cada uno de los cuales puede ser de un tipo diferente. Se trata de una lista ordenada, por lo que el orden en que se añaden los elementos se conserva.

JsonPrimitive: Esta clase representa un tipo de dato primitivo u objetos de datos simples (String, Integer, Double, etc.).

JsonNull: Representa un objeto a null.

Entonces si tu json es un array podras usar `element.getAsJsonArray();`.

Ahora modificas JsonObject:

```
jsonObj.add("nombreAtributo","valorAtributo"); // actualizas el valor de nombreAtributo o lo agregas si no existe.
```

Luego conviertes tu JsonObject a JsonString usando:

```
String json = gson.toJson(JsonObject);
```

Todo depende de la complejidad de tu json ya que por ejemplo dentro del objecto puedes tener un Array o otros objectos por lo la forma de como hacerlo puede variar un poco, puedes encontrar información mas detallada de como usar Gson en [Ejemplos Gson](https://jarroba.com/gson-json-java-ejemplos/)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Amigo, pero en la parte de editar mi JsonObj no tiene la opcion del put, es lo mismo que el add?

Comment: Hola, aquie esta la documentación de cada metodo https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html

Comment: claro que si puedes usar add o addProperty, revisa la documentación para ver cual t conviene según tu necesidad

Comment: muchísimas gracias compañero :)